# Can a generated number from a numbered list be used/referenced by another markup

Tags: markdown

New to markdown parsing, so looking for some advice on if this is even possible.
I'd like to reference the generated number value of a header or list as a value in a code block markup section.

Thought about using a jinja2 template but need the values after the markdown is rendered.  Thanks in advance.

Given the following markdown:

````
# Heading One

Source file:  heading-sequence-value.sql

1. Task One
    ```sql
       -- Task task-sequence-value
       CREATE TABLE table_name (column1 datatype);
    ```
1. Task Two
    ```sql
       -- Task task-sequence-value
       SELECT * FROM table_name;
    ```
````

Desired output:

1 Heading One

Script File: 1.sql

1. Task One

```sql
    -- Task 1
    CREATE TABLE table_name (column1 datatype);
```

2. Task Two

```sql
    -- Task 2
    SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Comment: you should be able to hack something together with either writing a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) or post-processing the generated HTML...

Comment: As a reminder, Markdown is a subset of HTML which gets rendered to HTML. You might find the answer by searching for how to accomplish your goal with HTML.